# Adding subscription address to chainlink vrf v2 inside of the contract

Tags: python, solidity, chainlink, brownie

So I'm writing this lottery smart contract which is pretty straight forward, and since I want to test this on the goerli test net, I want to be able to add the contract as a subscriber to my VRF every time it's deployed.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

    address owner;
    address[] buyers = [msg.sender];
    address winner;
    address vrfCoordinator = 0x2Ca8E0C643bDe4C2E08ab1fA0da3401AdAD7734D;

    bytes32 keyHash;

    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 5000000;
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 numWords = 1;
    uint256[] public randomWords;
    uint256 public requestId;
    uint64 subscriptionId;
    uint256 usdEntryFee;
    uint256 startingTime;
    uint256 endTime;
    uint256 prizePool;
    bool available;

    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function enterLottery() public payable returns (bool success) {
        buyers.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * 10**10; // 18 decimals
        // $50, $2,000 / ETH
        // 50/2,000
        // 50 * 100000 / 2000
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
        return costToEnter;
    }

    constructor(address _priceFeed, uint64 _subscriptionId)
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator)
    {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
        owner = msg.sender;
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        subscriptionId = _subscriptionId;
    }

    function requestRandomWords() public onlyOwner {
        requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            keyHash,
            subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );
    }

    function addSubscription() public {
        COORDINATOR.addConsumer(subscriptionId, address(this));
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256, // requestId
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        randomWords = _randomWords;
    }

    function startLottery(uint256 _endTime) public onlyOwner {
        startingTime = block.timestamp;
        available = true;
        endTime = startingTime + _endTime;
    }

    function endLottery() public payable onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
        require(
            block.timestamp > endTime,
            "Auction ending date not arrived yet!"
        );
        available = false;
        uint256 randomIndex;
        requestRandomWords();
        randomIndex = randomWords[0] % buyers.length;
        winner = buyers[randomIndex];
        return (randomWords[0]);
    }

    function transferWinnings() public payable onlyOwner {
        if (!payable(winner).send(prizePool)) {
            revert("Transaction failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using brownie framework to deploy and test, and this is the test function I'm using.

```
from brownie import Lottery, accounts, config, network
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account
from web3 import Web3

def test_random_number():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery.deploy(config["networks"][network.show_active()]["eth_usd_price_feed"], 1563, {"from": account})
    lottery.addSubscription({"from": account})
    lottery.requestRandomWords({"from": account})
    assert lottery.randomWords[0] != 0
```

I'm using the VRF admin wallet to do all of this but still it's not adding the contract to my subscriptions.

Also if anyone is familiar with how I could use the Chainlink VRF V2 mocks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using "subscriber" and "consumer" synonymously in regards to the contract using the subscription. Also, VRF v2 Mock can be found at [Chainlink GitHub](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix/blob/main/contracts/test/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol)

You can add the contract as a subscriber upon deployment in two ways:

1. set the contract as a subscriber within the `.py` file you're using for deployment
2. initialize the contract as a subscriber within the `.sol` contract itself

In both methods you will need to do two things in the following order: create a subscription, and add the contract as a consumer to that subscription. Your code only adds a consumer but does not actually create a subscription.

**1. Set contract as subscriber within the `.py` file:**

- source: [Medium article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/deploying-vrf-coordinator-v2-mock-for-local-blockchain-environments-26674903e4c9)
- `.py` deployment file: --> assuming deploying mock

`def deploy_VRFTest():`

```
account = accounts[0]
# deploy mock VRF coordinator ####################################################
# VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.deploy(_baseFee, _gasPriceLink, {"from": account})
vrf_contract = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.deploy(25 * 10e15, 10e9, {"from": account})
# create subscription & get subscription ID #######################################
sub_id_tx = vrf_contract.createSubscription({"from": account})
# add these waits so Web3 doesn't freak out and error, can also use time.sleep()
sub_id_tx.wait(1)
sub_id = sub_id_tx.events["SubscriptionCreated"]["subId"]  # get subscription ID
# fund subscription ################################################################
# must be greater than set _baseFee
fund_amount_link = 30 * 10e15
fund_vrf_tx = vrf_contract.fundSubscription(
    sub_id, fund_amount_link, {"from": account}
)
# request random words #############################################################
# goerli key_hash, can use any for development
key_hash = "0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15"
# blocks to wait before confirming random words (can be any #)
min_request_confirm = 3
gas_lim = 10e6  # 10e5 is recommended, added extra to be sure
num_words = 1  # number of random words
request_tx = vrf_contract.requestRandomWords(
    key_hash, sub_id, min_request_confirm, gas_lim, num_words, {"from": account}
)
request_tx.wait(1)
request_id = request_tx.events["RandomWordsRequested"]["requestId"]
# fulfill request ####################################################################
# deploy "ExampleContract.sol"
contract = ExampleContract.deploy(vrf_contract.address, {"from": account})
# fulfill random words ###############################################################
# vrf_contract.fulfillRandomWords(_requestId, _consumer, {"from": account})
fulfill_tx = vrf_contract.fulfillRandomWords(
    request_id, contract.address, {"from": account}
)
fulfill_tx.wait(1)
# return the random number ###########################################################
success = fulfill_tx.events["RandomWordsFulfilled"]["success"]
if success:
    random_word = contract.s_randomWords(0)
    print(f"random number is {random_word}")
time.sleep(10)
```

- `.sol` contract file:

  `pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;`

  `import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";`
  `import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";`

  ```
   contract ExampleContract is VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
       constructor(address _VRFCoordinator) VRFConsumerBaseV2(_VRFCoordinator) {}
       uint256[] public s_randomWords;
       function fulfillRandomWords(uint256, uint256[] memory randomWords)
           internal
           override
       {
           s_randomWords = randomWords;
       }
   }
  ```

**2. Set contract as subscriber within the `.sol` file:**

- source: [Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/subscription/examples/programmatic-subscription)
- the actual source has a few other functions but I removed them to codense
- `.sol` file:
- notice how the constructor for this file calls the `createNewSubcription()` function which not only creates a new subscription, but also adds the contract as a consumer to the subscription
  `pragma solidity ^0.8.7;`
  `import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";`
  `import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";`

  ```
   contract VRFTest is VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
   VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

   // Goerli coordinator
   address vrfCoordinator = 0x2Ca8E0C643bDe4C2E08ab1fA0da3401AdAD7734D;
   // The goerli gas lane to use, which specifies the maximum gas price to bump to.
   bytes32 keyHash =
       0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15;
   uint32 callbackGasLimit = 100000;
   uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
   uint32 numWords = 2;

   // Storage parameters
   uint256[] public s_randomWords;
   uint256 public s_requestId;
   uint64 public s_subscriptionId;
   address s_owner;

   constructor() VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator) {
       COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
       s_owner = msg.sender;
       //Create a new subscription when you deploy the contract.
       createNewSubscription();
   }

   // Assumes the subscription is funded sufficiently.
   function requestRandomWords() external onlyOwner {
       // Will revert if subscription is not set and funded.
       s_requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
           keyHash,
           s_subscriptionId,
           requestConfirmations,
           callbackGasLimit,
           numWords
       );
   }

   function fulfillRandomWords(
       uint256, /* requestId */
       uint256[] memory randomWords
   ) internal override {
       s_randomWords = randomWords;
   }

   // Create a new subscription when the contract is initially deployed.
   function createNewSubscription() private onlyOwner {
       s_subscriptionId = COORDINATOR.createSubscription();
       // Add this contract as a consumer of its own subscription.
       COORDINATOR.addConsumer(s_subscriptionId, address(this));
   }

   function addConsumer(address consumerAddress) external onlyOwner {
       // Add a consumer contract to the subscription.
       COORDINATOR.addConsumer(s_subscriptionId, consumerAddress);
   }

   modifier onlyOwner() {
       require(msg.sender == s_owner);
       _;
   }
   }
  ```